# What precautions need to be taken while installing a hardwood floor on a very old hardwood floor?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor

I am planning to install a [new](http://www.lumberliquidators.com/ll/c/Classic-Gunstock-Oak-Casa-de-Colour-PRGGSO3/10024877) solid hardwood floor on an existing hardwood floor(some variant of pine) - on the second floor of the 2-floor house. Rights now, we are considering putting an [underlayment](http://www.lumberliquidators.com/ll/c/Insulayment-SFT-ROLL-Dream-Home-INSUL/10014403). But we are concerned whether the current structure/floor will hold up the weight of the new floor and will not pose any security hazards for future. Are there any precautions we can take?

Comment: Consider how much bookcases -- or a waterbed -- would weigh. Consider how much a roomful of people weighs.
Usually the flooring isn't very significant on that scale. Going back to the underfloor before putting the new flooring in would reduce weight, but I'm not convinced you need to unless things are already marginal.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind not removing the old floor?